# DropDownListFor doesn't select element

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My controller:

```
var types = _opportunityTypeService.GetAll(); //has id 1,2,3,4
viewmodel.OpportunityTypes = new SelectList(types, "Id", "Name", recipe.Id); //recipe.Id is 4

return View(viewmodel);
```

and my view:
[image]

and the html result:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.DropDownListFor` creates a dropdownlist FOR a property. In your case for the property `m.OpportunityType`.

So the selected item will be what is in `m.OpportunityType`. The Selected property in the SelectList will be used when you use `Html.DropDownList`.

So your code would be:

```
var types = _opportunityTypeService.GetAll(); //has id 1,2,3,4
viewModel.OpportunityType = 4;
viewmodel.OpportunityTypes = new SelectList(types, "Id", "Name"); //recipe.Id is 4

return View(viewmodel);
```